# Prevent expectations already declared exception when testing AsyncRestTemplate

Tags: java, asynchronous, mocking, resttemplate, spring-test

How can one test `AsyncRestTemplate` requests and avoid the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expectations already declared` exception? The exception is thrown inconsistently for a single test case.

`Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expectations already declared
  at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
  at org.springframework.test.web.client.SimpleRequestExpectationManager.afterExpectationsDeclared(SimpleRequestExpectationManager.java:47)
  at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.validateRequest(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:73)
  at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer$MockClientHttpRequestFactory$1.executeInternal(MockRestServiceServer.java:289)
  at org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpRequest.execute(MockClientHttpRequest.java:94)
  at org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockAsyncClientHttpRequest.executeAsync(MockAsyncClientHttpRequest.java:50)
  at org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate.doExecute(AsyncRestTemplate.java:503)
  at org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate.execute(AsyncRestTemplate.java:463)
  at org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(AsyncRestTemplate.java:217)
  at com.company.MainClient.getStatus(MainClient.java:151)
  at com.company.MainController.status(MainController.java:88)`

The application aggregates data from several downstream systems. Requiring it to make several requests. Some of the requests are made asynchronously with the Future being handled later. Other requests block the main thread by immediately calling `asyncRestTemplateResponse.get()`.

The following test causes the error:

> Note: Server is `MockRestServiceServer`

```
@Test
public void statusTest() throws Exception {
    cServer.expect(once(),requestTo("http://localhost:8080/heartbeat"))
        .andRespond(withSuccess(cStatus, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    cpServer.expect(once(),requestTo("http://localhost:8081/status"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(cpStatus, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    tServer.expect(once(),requestTo("http://localhost:3030/check"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(tStatus, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    tServer.expect(once(),requestTo("http://localhost:3031/check"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(tStatus, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    tServer.expect(once(),requestTo("http://localhost:3032/check"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(tStatus, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/status").with(user(USERNAME).password(PASSWORD).roles("T_CLIENT")))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code").value("200"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.appDescription").value("Main Service"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.gateways[?(@.responseCode =~ /200/)]").isArray());

    //Test without basic auth
    mockMvc.perform(get("/status"))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I got a similar failure that you may be interested in:  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16132

Answer (score 0):

Per Eric Pabst's note above, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16132 seems to identify this as an issue. I am using Brussels-SR5. I set the <spring.version> property to 4.3.13.RELEASE and the problem went away.